# Is it UB to Modify where pointer points, when original data is const?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, undefined-behavior

Would it be undefined behavior to change where a pointer points, when its data is const? Example:

```
const char* p = "foo";
p = "boo";
```

I believe that this is not UB, because the pointer itself is not const and I'm not modifying the `"foo"` object.

Extra question: and altering not const data of a const pointer? Would be UB? Example:

```
char* const p = "foo";
(*(char**)&p) = (char*)malloc(strlen(p));
```

Comment: Your first example is fine. You have a non-const pointer to const data, you are free to re-assign the pointer. For that to fail to compile you'd have to have `const char* const p = "foo";`

Comment: I changed the second example. I meant wrongly. Sorry. It was without const.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I believe that this is not UB, because the pointer itself is not const and I'm not modifying the "foo" object.

This is correct.  The pointer is not `const` so you can change it to point to something else if you want.  In this case it won't cause a meory leak but remember that if the pointer points to data allocated with `new` and it is the only pointer to that data then you need to call `delete` before reassigning the pointer otherwise you'll have a meory leak.

> Extra question: and removing the constness of pointer? Would be UB?

It is only UB if you try to modify a `const` object you removed `const` from, which you do in this case.  Just removing `const` is okay, and sometimes needed, but you are never allowed to modify the object unless it was not `const` to begin with.  For example the following is legal since `foo` is not `const`.

```
int foo = 42;

void bar(int const& baz) { const_cast<int&>(baz) = 21; }

int main()
{
    bar(foo);
}
```

on the other hand

```
const int foo = 42;

void bar(int const& baz) { const_cast<int&>(baz) = 21; }

int main()
{
    bar(foo);
}
```

is not legal as `foo` is `const`

Comment: Just one more little question. In the second example if my data is not const: `char* const p = "foo";`, doing `(*(char**)&p) = (char*)malloc(strlen(p));` is UB?

Comment: @JoãoPaulo In your second example `p` is `const` so it is UB.  `char const *` is a non-const pointer to a `const char`.  `char * const` is a `const` pointer to a non-const `char`.

Answer (score 2):

The code in the first snippet is 100% correct. You have a pointer to const `p`, which you repoint to something else. All good and in mint condition.

The second piece of code is ill-formed. You can't modify an object after removing the constness, if original object was const-qualified (which string literal is).