# UB when changing non const data of const pointer

Tags: c++, casting, constants, undefined-behavior

I think the example bellow is UB:

```
const int v = 0;
const int* const p = &v;
(*(int**)&p) = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

But I'd like to know if this one is UB:

```
int v = 0;
int* const p = &v;
(*(int**)&p) = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Does `(int**)` cast returns a temporary? If yes, this temporary is non const, then the assign would not be a problem, I believe...

QUESTION: Are these examples UB?

Comment: [Per yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170163/is-it-ub-to-modify-where-pointer-points-when-original-data-is-const/58170220#58170220), this is still UB.  You can't modify a const object.

Comment: `Does (int**) cast returns a temporary?` Yes. `If yes, this temporary is non const, then the assign would not be a problem` No, because you're not assigning to the temporary. You indirect through the temporary pointer and assign to the pointed (pointer) object which is const.

Comment: Both are ub, since you assign to a constant pointer, whatever what it points to don't matter.

Comment: What bothers me is this: `(int**)&p`. The resulting object is not constant... Then dereferencing it would lead in a new new pointer object that points to the same place of `p`.

Comment: If you change your code to use `static_cast` instead of c-style cast you'll see the compiler refuse to perform the dangerous cast.

Comment: *The resulting object is not constant...* But it is.  You create the object in the same space where the const object is so the temporary is constant as well.  C++ **does not allow you to modify const objects in any way**

Comment: @NathanOliver understood. Thanks for your help. Just by curiosity, I came with this doubt by this [link](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-commits/Week-of-Mon-20190422/646945.html)

Comment: @JoãoPaulo the thing is, it might be a new pointer or not, the pointer points to a constant object. That constant object is `p`. The temporary pointer (not const) points to `p` which is const. Then, you dereference the pointer and assign to `p`. Assigning to `p` is the undefined behaviour

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot perfect. Fully understood now.

Comment: @JoãoPaulo `then dereferencing it would lead in a new new pointer object` No. Indirecting through a pointer does not result in a new object. It results in an lvalue to an existing object.